# How can I get Typescript to understand what the value type of a homogenous object is without losing keys from static declaration?

Tags: typescript

How can I get Typescript to understand what the value type of an object is without losing access to the key information from its static declaration?

In the below code I want the benefit of

- TS knowing the type of the value, in this case a function so I don't have to specify it's signature every time.
- TS knowing the keys of the object from static declaration so I can reference them in a type safe fashion from elsewhere

This object is homogenous and will have lots of functions, specifying the signature every time seems like a pain.

Example 1 - TS doesn't know the keys of the object

```js
    interface Foo {
        [key: string]: (n: number) => any
    }
    
    const obj1: Foo = {
        // TS already knows that `n` is a number 
        bar(n) {return n}
    }
    
    type KeyOfObj1 = keyof typeof obj1
    const kob1: KeyOfObj1 = "xyz" // This does not fail static type checking
```

Example 2 - TS doesn't know the signature of the functions which are the object's values

```js
    const obj2 = {
        // Notice here I have to specify the type of `n` 
        bar(n: number) {return n}
    }
    
    type KeyOfObj2 = keyof typeof obj2
    const kob2: KeyOfObj2 = "xyz" // This fails static type checking
```

How can I get the best of both worlds?

p.s. I understand I could pull out the keys into an enum but that seems rather ugly and repetitive, though perhaps it really is the only way

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a fairly common situation: you want to write an object, have its members contextually typed according to some weaker type (`Foo` in this case), but still retain the stronger type for some other purpose (in this case, you don't want to "forget" what the keys are).

The usual thing to do is to write a generic identity function, like below, which checks that the argument type `T` is a subtype of `Foo`, while returning the stricter type `T`:

```
function foo<T extends Foo>(obj: T): T {
    return obj;
}
```

Then when you create the object, the compiler will contextually type it as if it is some subtype of `Foo`, but still keep that subtype (with its specific key names) for the assignment to `obj`:

```
const obj = foo({
    foo(n) { return n + 1; },
    bar(n) { return n * 2; },
});

// 'foo' | 'bar'
type ObjKeys = keyof typeof obj
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGIHt3IN4ChkHIDaA1gFzIDOYUoA5gLoUAUAHhSAK4C2ARtAEpkAXgB8yTiBIh0AdxC4AvrlwxJCMMHQhkMTAB4AKsgitIIACaU0mUc3S8AVhUMCXOfISgQwnKDodHAG4lFQRtamRAkV1MZjxCWPRmECFsZG9ff2QdAGpkAEYg5EUAGk8CXjgoFLSMnz8dHQAqZAAmYrKlARDcAHo+5AByPXQh5AAfYaqoIdwwAE8ABxQAeScAaQgF62FkEm30GGRFlaOop1wgA)

Unfortunately, at least right now, you do need the generic identity function for this to work. There is currently [a proposal](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/47920) to add new syntax to the language which would allow this kind of problem to be solved without adding a "useless" extra function.

Comment: Had no idea about that proposal. Seems like a very good idea!

Comment: I've verified it against my use case and it solves my problem.  Thank you for a great answer!

Comment: @kaya3, thanks for this answer. Is there a way to make a more re-usable `foo` function where I can pass the weaker type (Foo) rather than have `Foo` baked into the function?

Comment: @Aaronius Only with currying, since you want one type parameter specified and the other inferred: `function makeChecker<T>() { return <S extends T>(x: S) => x; }`